# Cannot access property of null/undefined in my component.html

Tags: typescript, angular6

I'm new to Angular and I try to set up an application which should retrieve a user data stored in localstorage et display some properties of this item in my navbar.

My navbar is the header.component
My currentUser format has a property called "firstName"

I checked in the localstorage and my item is well present. When i reload my browser, I have no error so the property is correctly displayed. If i set a timeout before retrieving the item, it also ok.

So I guess my component is not loaded yet at the time I try to access it but i can't find how I should have done this.

I have looked for many solutions but i can't found the one working for me.

app.component.html

```
    <app-header></app-header>
<div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <alert></alert>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

header.component.html

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" routerLinkActive="active">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="btn-group navbar-nav ml-auto" dropdown>
      <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle"
              aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
        {{currentUser.firstName}}<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
          role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/login']" >Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

header.component.ts

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
        export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
      currentUser: User;

      constructor(
      ) {


        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

      }

      ngOnInit() {}
      }
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch your data on ngOnInit method and not on the constructor:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

@TheYoungStillThere,  try this..

currentUser is `undefined` by the time the template rendered. So initialize it with new Object and use safe operator in your html template as well.

```
currentUser = new User();//initialize your object like this

  constructor( ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }
```

assign values at `ngOnInit()` rather than `constructor` for more details about [life cycle hooks of angular check here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

**in  html template**

```
 <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle"
              aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
        {{currentUser?.firstName}}<span class="caret"></span>
```

Comment: The null reference is gone thanks to "?." operator but my property is still not displayed :/

Comment: what is your  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) returning..

Comment: Null the first time. My localstorage json item if I reload the browser or if I put a settimeout

Comment: I think you are trying to get the `currentUser` before you are setting it to `locaStorage`. check it once

Comment: My item in localstorage is probably not set when my header component renders but I'd like to know how I can display this value once my localstorage is set